# PHP: optimize regexp+substr

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to optimize the following PHP code so that I can only use preg_replace and not preg_replace+substr?

```
$type = substr( preg_replace('/([^a-z])/', '$2', strtolower($_GET["type"])) , 0, 3);
```

Comment: What is it you want to do? There is no `$2` in that regex by the way...

Comment: In some regexes, missing references are just treated as blank, so the $2 may effectively just remove the matches.

Comment: Yes, it does, but so does `''`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I would keep it simple and just alert the user if they entered an invalid string:

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]{0,3}$/', $type)) {
    // Handle error properly here.
    die('Type argument must be a string of 0-3 lower case letters (a-z)');
}
```

If you really want to fix the input, then your original solution was fine, it could just be cleaned up a little:

```
$type = substr(preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/', '', strtolower($_GET['type'])), 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

As people noted in comments, your code sample is kinda dysfunctional, but if I understand what you want to do correctly (retrieve the first three lowercase alphabetic characters), then this should do it:

```
$type = preg_replace('/.*?([a-z])(?:.*?([a-z]))?(?:.*?([a-z]))?.*/', '$1$2$3', strtolower($_GET['type']));
```